# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BTEncryption",

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I need to encrypt ccNumber  in my app. From string to encrypted string . thats why I am trying to use braintree. But this error generates. can not resolve this using several tricks available in web. need help.[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to link the simulator build against the ARM release of the braintree library.

Either you have imported the framework incorrectly or they have shipped you a bad release.